# get the value between round bracket java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

```
var string = "(a) (b)";
```

I want to split the above string into array

The output should be

```
[0] => 'a'
[1] => 'b'
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your attempt.

Comment: `{'a', 'b'}` is not an array...

Comment: Its a dictionary

Comment: [*Disclaimer:* I **hate** regex.](https://jsfiddle.net/edetcyhd/1/).

Comment: @Oqhax technically, it's a syntax error. Although to be fair to the OP that part was edited in to their question for some unknown reason. It's since been removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get everything enclosed by round brackets, the following should work

```js
var string = "(a) d (b)";
console.log(string.match(/[^()]+(?=\))/g));
```

Above will match even if the text has only a closing bracket - e.g. `"a) d (b)"` would result in `["a","b"]` too. If this is not intended, you can use

```
string.match(/\([^()]+(?=\))/g)
    .map(e => e.substring(1))
```

Comment: Not the OP but could you explain the regex as I'd like to learn regex and I suck at it.

Comment: @Script47 The `(?=\))` is a positive lookahead, so it will match every "word" that is followed by a closing bracket. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: fyi (not going to downvote), you need to correct it a bit. It doesn't cover all cases. Eg try `(foo) (erzats%bar) eaze (lorum)`

Comment: Thanks @KarelG. Edited it